# Sencha touch 2 event listener on text change for an input type=text html field

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a view. I'm trying to attach an `onchange` listener for an input field. I know how to do it with a textfield but I have a very specific setup I need to use html fields. How can I get the listener below to work, so if i change text in the field, I get some output in my console.

```
Ext.define('A.view.Viewa', {
    xtype: 'Viewa',

    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    config: {
        title: 'Title',
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },

        items: [

            {
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                scrollable: true,
                items: [

                ],
                html: [
                    "<input type='text' value='changeme' id='changetext'/>"
                ].join("")
            }
        ],

        listeners  :  {
                       change : {
                            fn: function() {
                                console.log("Yes it works!!");

                            },
                            delegate : '#changetext',
                            element : 'element'
                       }              
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it with your `change` listener but that does not work. The `keyup` listener seems to work fine.

```
Ext.define('A.view.Viewa', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'Viewa',

    config: {
        html: '<input type="text" value="changeme" id="changetext"/>',
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        scrollable: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        listeners: {
            keyup: {
                fn: function() {
                    console.log("Yes it works!!");
                },
                delegate: '#changetext',
                element: 'element'
            }
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Title'
            }
        ]
    }

});
```